# sound levels in alsamixer versus sound levels in the 'sound settings' menu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

the maximum volume alsamixer allows me to reach is 100%

the 'sound settings' menu (on the upper right corner) allows levels beyond 100%

Why are these levels not reachable via alsamixer ? Is this related to some deep fact about the sound architecture, or is it incidental ? Are those volumes only acessible via pulse (i.e. is alsa unaware of them) ?

Comment: bonus: what does a volume beyond 100% even mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Percentages are always relative.

In `alsamixer`, 100% is the maximum value of the mixer control.

In PulseAudio, 100% is 0 dB.

(Please note that this still doesn't tell you anything about the absolute volume level.)